# VS 2010 Setup Project show form conditionally

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, installation, conditional-statements, setup-project

I'm creating a setup for my application. The application consists of a `main application` and an `AddIn to Outlook`. I wish, that the user is able to select by checkbox, if Outlook AddIn should be installed.
My problem is, I don't want to show/enable that checkbox if outlook is not installed.
How can I achieve this? Can I somehow show `install dialog` conditionally, base on some code, where I would check if Outlook is installed? Or can I disable this checkbox base on some code?
Please help,
thanks a lot!
Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to identify if Outlook is installed you need to define a search in the MSI package.

Then, to show a dialog based on a condition you need to edit the published events for a couple of buttons (Back and Next) from the surrounding dialogs.

To show a control conditionally on a dialog you need to use a control condition.

All of this is not possible to do in a VS Setup Project. I would recommend switching to WiX (http://wix.sourceforge.net/) if you are looking for an a better free alternative, this can integrate with VS too. I would switch from VS Setup project and because Microsoft decided to stop including it in VS 2012, so then you will be forced to stop using it.

If you don't want to go to WiX right now, the only way to do what you need in VS is to add a post-build event that alters the MSI tables and [inserts the changes you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368568%28VS.85%29.aspx), i.e. the search, control condition, etc...